# How to convert a display toggle effect to CSS 3 Transitions effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

**First of all I have to say that I'm working on website which I can only manipulate its CSS.**
So, please don't suggest me a javascript/html solution.

Here is my problem,

You can see in this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tRTgE/1), there is a basic toggle display method but it doesn't have a transitions effect on default CSS. The HTML is exactly like that, and I don't have a permission to change its HTML or javascript, I can only play with CSS.

I want to add CSS 3 Transitions effect to this toggle method.

[As Jim Jeffers's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/603127), transitions effect never works on

`display: block` < - >  `display: none`

So I will always need to keep the element display block.

I tried this but it didn't work,

```
.infocontent {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
div[style='display: block; '].infocontent { 
   opacity: 1; height: auto !important;
}
div[style='display: none; '].infocontent {
   display:block !important;  opacity: 0; height: 0px; 
}
```

Why isn't it working? How can I do that?

Comment: I'm having the same issue where I can't use fx jquery .hide(100) or .show(100) functions cuz they make weird spacing on my site (which is unacceptable). If I use display:block; and display:none; however the spacing is gone, but im lacking the cool transition effect you get with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use transition on max-height instead of height.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to transition the height, just the opacity. I'm not sure how this is actually supposed to look, though; the height seems like the natural thing to transition in this case.

Comment: Yes,the height seems like the natural thing to transition in this case, but you cannot transition from height: auto; (that's why I suggested max-height).

Comment: @Ana, no it's not working, actually I can set a specific height, it's not important.http://jsfiddle.net/tRTgE/2/

Comment: Man, sometimes I feel like I'm just speaking a made-up language or something.